# why after splashscreen runs a bit slow to form1 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, splash-screen

is there a solution so that after the splashscreen so can go directly to form1? And is there something wrong with my code and is it because I created a splachscreen from a Windows Form instead of from a custom splashscreen?

Thanks

Here's [a link] video (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1URn_DDTnu3h1oERhwFGPCa9-9Se1H_g9/view?usp=share_link)!

```
Imports WinFormAnimation
Public Class FormWelcome
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        CircularProgressBar1.Value += 1
        CircularProgressBar1.Text = CircularProgressBar1.Value.ToString
        If Me.Opacity < 1 Then
            Me.Opacity += 0.05
        End If
        If CircularProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer2.Start()
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub FormWelcome_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CircularProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Me.Opacity = 0
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Me.Opacity -= 0.1
        If Me.Opacity = 0 Then
            Timer2.Stop()
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "why after splashscreen runs a bit slow to form1 in vb.net" Define `slow` please. There is a delay between the splash screen disappearing and form1 appearing? Form1 appears but runs sluggish? What? Maybe a video showing what you mean might help...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, `There is a delay between the splash screen disappearing and form1 appearing?` sorry i was late replying, yes right you mean delay.

Comment: What framework are you targeting? I'm not sure whether it's been added to .NET Core but .NET Framework has splash screen functionality built in so you should be using that if you can.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `What framework are you targeting?` I use Net Framework 4.7.2